# Spring application in WebSphere. Setup of JMS message listener invoker failed

Tags: java, spring, jms, websphere

I have a spring application deplyoed in WebSphere container and I need to configure JMS but I have a problem. Sending messages works fine but MessageListener doesn't consumes messages.

This is my jms config:

```
@Bean
public PlatformTransactionManager transactionManager() {
    return new WebSphereUowTransactionManager();
}

@Bean
public ConnectionFactory jmsConnectionFactory() throws NamingException {
    return jndi().lookup(CONNECTION_FACTORY_ADDRESS, ConnectionFactory.class);
}

@Bean(name = "queue")
public Queue jmsQueue() throws NamingException {
    return jndi().lookup(QUEUE_ADDRESS, Queue.class);
}

@Bean(name = "replyQueue")
public Queue jmsReplyQueue() throws NamingException {
    return jndi().lookup(REPLY_QUEUE_ADDRESS, Queue.class);
}

@Bean
public DestinationResolver jmsDestinationResolver() {
    return new JndiDestinationResolver();
}

@Bean
public DefaultJmsListenerContainerFactory jmsListenerContainerFactory() throws NamingException {
    final DefaultJmsListenerContainerFactory factory = new DefaultJmsListenerContainerFactory();
    factory.setConnectionFactory(jmsConnectionFactory());
    factory.setDestinationResolver(jmsDestinationResolver());
    factory.setTransactionManager(transactionManager());
    factory.setSessionTransacted(true);
    factory.setConcurrency("3-10");
    factory.setTaskExecutor(threadPoolTaskExecutor());
    return factory;
}

@Bean
public TaskExecutor threadPoolTaskExecutor() {
    ThreadPoolTaskExecutor executor = new ThreadPoolTaskExecutor();
    executor.setCorePoolSize(5);
    executor.setMaxPoolSize(10);
    executor.setQueueCapacity(50);
    executor.setKeepAliveSeconds(20);

    return executor;
}
```

I get this exception on startup:

```
[08.06.17 18:23:38:765 MSK] 00000409 DefaultMessag W org.springframework.jms.listener.DefaultMessageListenerContainer handleListenerSetupFailure Setup of JMS message listener invoker failed for destination 'jms/test_queue' - trying to recover. Cause: No JTA UserTransaction available - programmatic PlatformTransactionManager.getTransaction usage not supported
```

I read that It can be cause of the conflict with hibernate transitive dependency. I've tried to exclude `jboss-transaction-api_1.1_spec` dependency from hibernate-core but it didn't help.

I've also tried to use WorkManagerTaskExecutor:

```
@Bean
public TaskExecutor taskExecutor() {
    WorkManagerTaskExecutor executor = new WorkManagerTaskExecutor();
    executor.setWorkManagerName("wm/default");
    return executor;
}
```

But exception is still throws.

What could be the problem?

Comment: Have you tried to use the WebSphereUOWTransactionManager in place of the PlatformTransactionManager?

Comment: @Alasdair I'm already using `WebSphereUOWTransactionManager`. I tried to set return type of transactionManager bean to WebSphereUOWTransactionManager but result was the same